# Image not loading from file path in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to load the image from the saved file path of that image that is stored in my iPhone. I am getting the path but still it says file does not exist. This is my code :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.imageName]];
        BOOL fileExists=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];
        NSLog(@"%@",imagePath);
        UIImage *fetchImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

fileExists returns **NO** even when I get this path :

> /var/mobile/Applications/2ED5C185-8528-48D3-BE0B-28582DC3D294/Documents/IMG_0028.JPG

Comment: First Check in doc. have you image, name is `IMG_0028.JPG` ?

Comment: yes, i am fetching the image name using ALAssetsLibrary. The image name is dynamic and not hard-coded.

Comment: File names are case sensitive on the device. Please make sure your image name and case is exactly as "IMG_0028.JPG". They are NOT case sensitive on the simulator.

Comment: check if(fetchImage == nil) or not ?

Comment: I am not using simulator. I am using a real device. And the image name is not hard-coded. So, I am using the same image name that it fetches using ALAssetsLibrary.

Comment: @iPatel the problem is that it is giving me the file path, so it should load the image using that path. But still it does not load it.

Comment: Your code has not any mistake so problem is other, if your file path is correct then your `fetchImage` should not be `nil`.

Comment: How do you get self.imageName? Can you show code for it?

Comment: Try deleting app from device and re-install it again.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem as well. Hopefully this will save someone a headache down the road.

You can't rely on the Documents Directory to stay consistent from one build to the next. When you re-deploy the app this path could change:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/2ED5C185-8528-48D3-BE0B-28582DC3D294/Documents/
```

My problem was I was storing the Document Path in a JSON file and trying to retrieve it on subsequent builds. This piece changes on every build:

> 2ED5C185-8528-48D3-BE0B-28582DC3D294

Store only the filename with extension and pull the Document Path dynamically. Then you can proceed to prefix the path on the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it work fine for me

```
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",self.imageName ];
      NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
      BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
      if (fileExists) {
        NSLog(@"alreday Exists");
       }
```

// for showing image on image view

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDir,self.imageName];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image =[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.aStrImagePath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try with following code :

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.JPG",self.imageName]];
    BOOL fileExists=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath];
    NSLog(@"%@",imagePath);
    UIImage *fetchImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSString *strNew=[dci valueForKey:@"uThumbPath"];
    NSString *strCompare=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[self MD5String:strNew]];
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",documentsPath);
    NSString *strFileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsPath,strCompare];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:strFileName])
    {
        NSLog(@"Downloaded From Localpath");
        NSString *inputPath= strFileName;
        NSString *extension=[inputPath pathExtension];
        NSString *file=[[inputPath lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        NSString *dir=[inputPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
        NSString *imagePATH=[NSBundle pathForResource:file ofType:extension inDirectory:dir];
       UIImage* theImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePATH];
        cell.imgThumb.image=theImage;

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Downloaded From Server");
        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: [dci valueForKey:@"uThumbPath"]];
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        NSLog(@"%@",strNew);
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                                   NSData * data1,
                                                   NSError * error) {

                                   if (!error){

                                       [self saveLocally:data1 name:strNew];
                                       cell.imgThumb.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data1];

                                   }

                               }];

    }
```

and use this

```
- (NSString *)MD5String:(NSString *)string{
    const char *cstr = [string UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5(cstr, strlen(cstr), result);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3],
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this just happen to me. XCode didn't update my files correctly after adding it to my project. Try to do a clean (Product -> Clean) and see if that fixes the issue.